# Removing a website from Firefox Suggest Without Deleting History

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

When using the search bar in Firefox, can I blacklist a specific website and its subdomains from Firefox Suggest? Basically I want to use the search bar without seeing results from a specific website (these results appear because they are in my history). Searching online, the only solution I've found is to remove that website from my history, but I don't want to do this.

Comment: If you don't remove a website from history, it will appear among the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox start typing in the URL of the website you want to remove from the suggestion list. Once the suggested URL appears in the list, use the arrow keys on your keyboard to highlight it.

Next, hold down the Shift key and then press the Delete key. Doing this will remove the suggested URL from the list, but it won't delete your browsing history for that website.

**Edit:**

Suggested URLs are stored in `places.sqlite` in the subfolder that ends with `.default-release` in the `Firefox/Profiles/` folder for W10.

Close Firefox and get a backup of `places.sqlite`, then open the file in [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), then go to the **Execute SQL** tab and use this command to remove all the subdomains for `website.com`:

```
DELETE FROM moz_places
WHERE url LIKE '%website.com%';
```

then hit the **Play** button. This deletes all the suggested URLs that contain in the URL the name `website.com`.
Now hit the **Close Database** button and you can open Firefox.

The rectangles marked with red are the ones of interest:
[image]

As you can see, all suggested URLs are stored in **moz_places**, accessed by going to **Browse Data**. [Frecency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frecency#:%7E:text=%22Frecency%20is%20a%20score%20given,URI%20was%20bookmarked%20or%20tagged.%22) is the parameter that determines which suggested URL is more important.

If you want to delete more entries at once you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM moz_places
WHERE url LIKE '%google.com%' 
OR url LIKE '%bing.com%'
OR urk LIKE '%yahoo.com%';
```

**Edit 1:**

To automatically remove all entries for `www.website.com/*` from Firefox for Windows 10 take these steps:

0. Make a backup of `places.sqlite`
1. Install [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and make sure during installation to add Python to the system **PATH**, as seen here:
   [image]
2. Save this code as `remove_suggested_URLS_Firefox.bat`:

```bat
@echo off
py -3 "remove_suggested_URLS_Firefox.py"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    @REM If the path to firefox.exe is not the one below, then you
    @REM you have to change it with the current path to it.
    "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
)
```

3. Save this code as `remove_suggested_URLS_Firefox.py`:

```py
import sqlite3

# Replace the path below with the path that points to places.sqlite for you.
path = r"C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\abcd.default-release\places.sqlite"
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
c = conn.cursor()

# Replace 'website.com' and 'website1.com' with the domains you want removed.
# Also, you can add as many domains as you want, just make sure to add a comma between them, as in the example below.
links = ['website.com', 'website1.com']
for link in links:
    c.execute("DELETE FROM moz_places WHERE url LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", (link,))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

4. Make sure both files are saved in the same place.
5. Read the content of both files marked with `@REM` (for .bat) and `#` (for .py) and make the appropriate changes.
6. Instead of opening Firefox, just run `remove_suggested_URLS_Firefox.bat`, which will remove all the suggested URLs for the given domain/s and it will launch Firefox.
7. If you don't want the cmd window to show up each time you run the .bat, then follow these steps:

- 1. Create a shortcut to the .BAT file
- 2. Right click on the shortcut and choose Properties.
- 3. In the Run: drop down, choose Minimized.
- 4. Click OK.
- 5. Double-click the shortcut to run the batch file in a minimized window state.

8. Now you can move the shortcut wherever you want.

Comment: I'm able to delete specific URLs with this method, however, it doesn't delete the entire domain. For example, I can use this to delete a suggestion such as `www.website.com/subdomain1`, however, `www.website.com/subdomain2` will still be suggested unless I also manually delete that. Am I able to delete all subdomains stemming from `www.website.com/`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to delete all subdomains stemming from `www.website.com/`. I'll return tomorrow with an answer since I'll have to do a bit of research.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question: Is there a way to prevent `www.website.com/*` from appearing in Firefox Suggest in the future, or will I have to periodically go back and delete the entries since I visit the website often.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Check out the updated answer marked with **Edit 1**.

Comment: The place were I work recently changed domain names, and I tried everything in this thread to get rid of old entries from the suggestions. I finally figured it out today. There's a moz_origins table that holds all the host names you've ever been to. I had to also remove the old domains from there. Now I'm finally free of them!
Maybe you could add moz_origins to the answer?

Comment: I started working on a more advanced version of this program, but I had to put it on hold as I had other things to do. When I get back to it, I'll have a look at what you suggested.